# How can I resize an iframe on the parent page, when AJAX updates data on the page inside the iframe?

Tags: jquery, ajax, iframe, resize

I have a page with an iframe - and a page that is loaded inside of that iframe. The trouble is - that many controls on the child page use AJAX. And when AJAX changes the child page elements height - the whole page height changes... and iframe gets scrollbars.

I came up with an idea like this:

```
$("#iframe").contents().click(function()
{
    $("#iframe").height($("iframe").contents().height() +20);
})
```

But!!! An AJAX request lasts longer then the click event... and so - my iframe gets the old height of the child page - right before the AJAX changes it...

Any ideas about how can I define height change on the child page? Or maybe bind some ajaxComplete or ajaxStop events to the child page?

Comment: You've already answered your own question: [`ajaxComplete()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/), just do the same thing, but then register it using `ajaxComplete()` instead of on `click()`.

Comment: I've tried to do it - but it doesn't work...(( Seems like the parent page - that has an iframe can't access the events on the child page - that is loaded into an iframe.